# Update/Install mysql-client to version 5.7 using yum

Tags: mysql, linux, chef-infra, yum

I was writing my own chef recipe to install only the mysql client version 5.7 and not the server. I was trying to do this using yum and had written my own chef recipe, but it by default adds the version 5.5 instead of 5.7 and I am not able to update only the client to 5.7 using yum so that I could write my own recipe on chef.

When I give the version field in my recipe, it throws an error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things in Chef, it only does what you tell it. If there isn't a MySQL 5.7 package available in your configured yum repos, the `package` resource will error. We offer a `yum_repository` resource if you want to configure a new package source with newer versions, or you could use an `rpm_package` resource to install a single package directly if you make one yourself.